# R how to do the partial row sums

Tags: r, sum, sumifs

I am very new to R, and I sincerely appreciate your help.

The following is part of my data:

```
subjectID  A B C D E F G H I J
S001       1 1 1 1 1 0 0
S002       1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I want to sum the rows from A to J, and so the data will look like this:

```
subjectID A B C D E F G H I J TOTAL
S001      1 1 1 1 1 0 0        5
S002      1 1 1 0 0 0 0        3
```

Thank you so much! I would like sum if variable A to J == 1.

Comment: Try to search for `?rowSums`; it does exactly what the name might suggest. Or `apply(your_data, 1, function(x) sum(x[x == 1]))` or with `mutate` of `dplyr` package. There are several ways you can do that but next time please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in order to help users help you and **first** al all: try to search. I bet there are several questions to your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "if variable A to J == 1"? In your example, there is no value for H, I and J.

Comment: to my previous comment do not forget to add the `na.rm = T` to the `sum` function. But since your output (with no elements to H, I, J --  most likely empty strings) I bet they are character maybe.

Comment: @SabDeM that should be an answer.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen maybe, I am just waiting moderators because most likely this question will be marked as duplicate and furthermore a `dput` of the data just to test my code.

Comment: Many questions are duplicates and that's ok. It's good to have a lot of examples to even marginally different problems.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I was thinking about how to do that with `dplyr`... maybe I am missing something but this is one of the very few cases in which `dplyr` is not a comfortable tool to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I post here my answers.
This is is with `apply`. the `df[-1]` is to exclude the first column (which is not numeric), the `x[x == 1]` is to subset the elements of `x` (a single row due to the `1` of the apply) with only values of 1.

```
 df$TOTAL <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) sum(x[x == 1], na.rm = T))
```

Another (I bet much faster and) easier to code way in base R is:

```
df$TOTAL <- rowSums(df[-1] == 1, na.rm = T)
```

both have as a result this

```
df
  subjectID A B C D E F G  H  I  J TOTAL
1      S001 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 NA NA NA     5
2      S002 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 NA NA NA     3
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(subjectID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("S001", 
"S002"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, 1L), B = c(1L, 1L), C = c(1L, 
1L), D = c(1L, 0L), E = c(1L, 0L), F = c(0L, 0L), G = c(0L, 0L
), H = c(NA, NA), I = c(NA, NA), J = c(NA, NA)), .Names = c("subjectID", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so stuck on the df[-1].

Answer (score 0):

Another similar option to the one posted by SabDeM but using `sapply` to sum only numeric columns

```
df$Total <- rowSums(df[ ,sapply(df, is.numeric)])
```

Output:

```
  subjectID A B C D E F G  H  I  J Total
1      S001 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 NA NA NA     5
2      S002 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 NA NA NA     3
```